# Poisson distribution in a bakery

Tags: probability

In a bakery mixing $100$kg of dough with $2$kg of raisin and baking from the mixture $400$ buns. Assume that the avarage weight of one raisin is $2$ grams and the number of raisins is poisson distributed

> - A. Find the parameter of the distribution
> - B. Find the probability that in bun there will be at least $2$ raisins

---

**My attempt:**

**A.** If we will take the $2$kg of raisin and will spred them over the $100$kg of dough, so for one kg of dough there will be $0.02$ grams of raisins so I think that $\lambda=2$

**B.** $P(X\geq 2)=1-P(X=1)\\
=1-\frac{\lambda^1}{1!}e^{-\lambda}\\
=1-\frac{2^1}{1!}e^{-2}\\
=1-2/e^2\approx 0.72$

Is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In A, you should be dividing the total weight of raisins by $100$.  That does not give $0.02$ g, which is only $1/100$ raisin.  Then convert the weight into expected number of raisins.

In B, you are using the wrong $\lambda$, but you need to subtract the probability of zero raisins as well.

Comment: The total weight of raisins is $2$kg so $2/100=0.02=1/50$kg$=2$grams, Is'nt it?

Comment: 2kg = 2000g / 2g, there are 1000 raisins. Divided by 400 buns, I'd say 2.5 for lambda

Comment: ohh sorry stupid mistake

Comment: @Pieter21 "there are 1000 raisins" we don't know how many raisins there are

Comment: if 2kg of raisins have an average of 2 gram each, there are 1000. You can conclude that safely. Name it EXPECTED number if you want.

Comment: @Pieter21 ohh yes, thanks I got it, your comment was needed